# TomEE server is not passing web service request to the webmethod

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am new in the area of SOAP Based web services. I am using TomEE server. The server is a bit customized according to my organization's need. 
Few days back, when I was trying to run the web services example from TomEE website, I was able to generate the wsdl and calling the web service by a client.
Now, when I need to use the customized version of TomEE plus (by the organization), I can see that the request does reach to the server and hence there is a log entry also but my @WebMethod is not getting executed.

Does any one has any idea about any configuration which can prevent the request from reaching to the webservice method? Is there any pointer around how can I debug further to reach out to the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about what is customized it's like fishing in the dark.
I would guess that perhaps the global web.xml or the server.xml of tomee server is changed so that some URI context mappings are not forwarded or ignored. But it's only a lucky tip.